# AWS Lambda function to repost a message to a topic with message attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying to create a Lambda function that will "sit" between two SNS topics, and publish to topic B whatever is coming to topic A.

Lambda Function

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var params = {
        Message: event.Records[0].Sns.Message,
        MessageAttributes: event.Records[0].Sns.MessageAttributes,
        Subject: event.Records[0].Sns.Subject,
        TopicArn: process.env.main_bus_topic_arn
    }

    var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

    publishTextPromise.then(
        function(data) {
            console.log(`Message ${params.Message} sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}`);
            console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
        }).catch(
            function(err) {
            console.error(err,err.stack);
        });
};
```

When I try to read the messageAttributes and forward them to topic B, I am getting the following errors:

Logs

```
2022-02-21T13:31:57.321Z    5698de94-f4d8-4136-87b6-126b910dc75d    ERROR   MultipleValidationErrors: There were 3 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'DataType' in params.MessageAttributes['sdfsdf']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Type' found in params.MessageAttributes['sdfsdf']
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Value' found in params.MessageAttributes['sdfsdf']
    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9
    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:396:7)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:414:9
    at EnvironmentCredentials.get (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:127:7)
    at getAsyncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:408:24)
    at Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:428:9) {
  code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
```

Is there an easy way of forwarding the messageAttributes like the Message and Subject? Without having to read the attributes and recreate them?

**Update**
When MessageAttributes are being read in the lambda function, they are in this format

```
{ testingAttr1: { Type: 'String', Value: 'AttrValues' } }
```

Publish API is expecting them to be formatted like below

```
{ 'testingAttr1': { DataType: 'String', StringValue: 'AttrValues' } }
```

Is there a way to avoid making this data transformation and just get them inside the Lambda and throw them directly into the publish API call?

Comment: Sidenote: can you not just publish to both topics at the same time? Just trying to rule out [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Unfortunately not.